# Pass token in header for authentication in MVC and Web API

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

Integrating MVC app with Web API, Azure Users Authentication is done using OWIN, Want to remove authentication cookie and pass token in header for api call. how to do it? I use MSAL.cs file for Azure AD authentication. Want to pass token in api call header. first load MVC application page, after authentication call web api methods. 
I used following code for azure AD autherization,

```
 private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
            {
                // Extract the code from the response notification
                var code = notification.Code;

                string signedInUserID = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, notification.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase).GetMsalCacheInstance();
                ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(ClientId, Authority, RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);
                try
                {
                    AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, Scopes);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //TODO: Handle
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or this question will likely be closed. Please include the relevant details (the cookie and header names, for example) in the question, as well as what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

After the first time sign in users from azure ad using the ASP.Net OpenID Connect OWIN middleware , if you want to call web api , you can add the token to request header :

```
string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier").Value;
string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Startup.aadInstance, tenantID, string.Empty);
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(Startup.clientSecret);

// Here you ask for a token using the web app's clientId as the scope, since the web app and service share the same clientId.
app = new ConfidentialClientApplication(Startup.clientId, redirectUri, credential, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID, this.HttpContext)){};
result = await app.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(new string[] { Startup.clientId });

 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, serviceUrl + "/api/todolist");
 request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.Token);

 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Please refer to [code sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/AppModelv2-WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet) for more details .